# Theming ubercart address panes

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I am trying theming checkout address panes using form alter.

```
function mymodule_theme() {
    return array(
        'billing_pane_theme' =>array(
            'render element' => 'form',
            'path'=> drupal_get_path('theme', 'twitter_bootstrap').'/templates/checkout',
            'template' => 'checkout-billing-fields',

        ),

        'delivery_pane_theme' => array(
            'render element' => 'form',
            'path'=> drupal_get_path('theme', 'twitter_bootstrap').'/templates/checkout',
            'template' => 'checkout-delivery-fields',

        ),

    );
}


function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if($form_id == 'uc_cart_checkout_form') {
        $form['panes']['billing']['#theme'] = 'billing_pane_theme';
        $form['panes']['delivery']['#theme'] = 'delivery_pane_theme';


    }
}
```

everything goes well at the first time when user click "Checkout" button or refresh checkout page, but if user choose "Saved addresses", or "My billing information is the same as my delivery information" (panes render through ajax request) then theme doesn't apply and default address field panes are showing

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the #ahah callback properties and check that the returned form trigger the alter, I guess it returns only a "slice" of the full form skipping your theme.

Comment: Yes muka You are correct, when ajax request processed then it returning only fields of checkout address pane.

Comment: Hi I have updated screen-shots before and after ajax request. Is there any way to apply theme.

Comment: Not sure about that but couldn't you return an already rendered form via ajax, like theme('your_uc_theme', $form, $form_state) [syntax is absolutely fictional:]